# Visual Source Safe Changelists

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, perforce

Maybe just maybe somebody knows of an plugin that will let VSS do perforce-like changelists? I know its a long shot, but we are stuck with VSS.

Comment: Well, considering that VSS can't even really version deletes properly, that would be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're stuck with VSS -- would switching to Team Foundation Server be an option?  It's basically the successor to VSS, and, if you're under direction to remain a "Microsoft shop", it may still satisy your requirements.  Team Foundation Server supports changelists (changesets -- whichever term you prefer).  [Summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server):

> Source control Team Foundation Server
>   provides a source control repository,
>   called Team Foundation Version Control
>   (TFVC). Unlike Microsoft's previous
>   source control offering, Visual
>   SourceSafe (VSS), which relied on a
>   file-based storage mechanism, Team
>   Foundation source control stores all
>   code, as well as a record of all
>   changes and current check-outs in an
>   SQL Server database. It supports
>   features such as multiple simultaneous
>   check-outs, conflict resolution,
>   shelving and unshelving (shelving is a
>   way to save a set of pending changes
>   without committing them to source
>   control, while still making them
>   available to other users), branching
>   and merging, and the ability to set
>   security levels on any level of a
>   source tree, alongside the most
>   visible features of document
>   versioning, locking, rollback, and
>   atomic commits. The source control
>   mechanism integrates with Team
>   System's work items as well; when a
>   check-in (termed "changeset") occurs,
>   a developer can choose to have his
>   code associated with one or more
>   specific work items, to indicate that
>   the check-in works towards solving
>   specific issues. TFS administrators
>   can enforce check-in policies that
>   require Code Analysis requirements to
>   have passed, as well as to enforce the
>   association of check-ins with work
>   items, or update the state of
>   associated work items (like flagging a
>   bug as "fixed" when checking in code
>   that has the bug fixed). Individual
>   versions of files can be assigned
>   labels, and all files with the same
>   label forms a release group. Unlike
>   VSS, TFS source control repository
>   does not support linking to an item
>   from multiple places in the source
>   folder structure, nor does it allow an
>   item to be "pinned" (allow different
>   references to the same file from
>   different directories to point to
>   different versions in a way that
>   cannot be further edited).
>
> TFVC supports branching at entire
>   source code level as well as
>   individual files and directory levels
>   as well, with each branch being
>   maintained individually. Multiple
>   branches can be merged together, with
>   the built in conflict resolution
>   algorithm merging the changes between
>   two branches of the same file where it
>   can automatically reconcile the
>   differences or flagging them for
>   manual inspection if it cannot. Merge
>   can be performed at "changeset" level
>   as well, instead of the branch level.
>   A successful merge is automatically
>   checked out in the source control
>   repository.
>
> TFVC is not limited to source code
>   only, but using the Windows SharePoint
>   Services infrastructure it is built
>   on, it provides a version-controlled
>   library for other documents in the
>   project as well, including project
>   plans, requirements and feature
>   analysis documents among others. All
>   documents in the source controlled
>   repository can be linked with any work
>   item, and access to them can be
>   controlled by defining access
>   policies.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe VSS supports this type of functionality. You should probably come up with a business case to management that describes your issues with VSS, and how switching to something else would reduce development risk and improve productivity.

There are numerous free/open source SCMs, as well as some commercial products (like Perforce) that are reasonably priced.

Good luck - I was in a similar situation at one point.